# How can ı get secret key google auth QRCode?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the secret key inside the exported QR code from your android Google Authenticator

[image]

When I can read qr code , i am getting this text like

otpauth-migration://offline?data=CjYKCjc0YTA3ZTliNTASE0VUSElDQS3EsEhTQU4gQUxUVU4aDWV0aGljYXNpZ29ydGEgASgBMAIQARgBIAA%3D

I am trying to reach the secret information from the information written in data. I can access this secret key with a plugin I found. how can i access it in c#

```
        byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\qr.jpeg");
        var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        var result = reader.Decode(bmp);
```

// result = otpauth-migration://offline?data=CjYKCjc0YTA3ZTliNTASE0VUSElDQS3EsEhTQU4gQUxUVU4aDWV0aGljYXNpZ29ydGEgASgBMAIQARgBIAA%3D

```
        var data = result.Text.Split('=')[1];

        var bs64 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data);
```

// bs64 = "CjYKCjc0YTA3ZTliNTASE0VUSElDQS3EsEhTQU4gQUxUVU4aDWV0aGljYXNpZ29ydGEgASgBMAIQARgBIAA="

```
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(bs64);
        
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes));
```

Console result:

[image]

But, this should be the correct output
otpauth://totp/ethicasigorta:ETHICA-%C3%84%C2%B0HSAN%20ALTUN?secret=G42GCMBXMU4WENJQ&issuer=ethicasigorta

I need this key "secret=G42GCMBXMU4WENJQ"

Comment: You seem to be getting the data correctly. What is the issue here?

Comment: not true unfortunately, that's right

otpauth://totp/ethicasigorta:ETHICA-%C3%84%C2%B0HSAN%20ALTUN?secret=G42GCMBXMU4WENJQ&issuer=ethicasigorta

I need a secret key ( secret=G42GCMBXMU4WENJQ )

Comment: Do you have a documentation link?

Comment: I added first post

Comment: @Llama link of the project i tried  https://disk.yandex.com.tr/d/Zoa6VIL9mQEotg

Comment: The thing I don't get is: when the QR code is otpauth-migration://offline, why do you expect it to be otpauth://totp? The QR code you have has the wrong scheme and path, so why do you expect the data to be correct?

Comment: but someone did. When you read qr code with this plugin. When I downloaded the backup it gave me the secret key I wanted.

https://github.com/Authenticator-Extension/Authenticator

https://disk.yandex.com.tr/i/gQEklOEg2J3Y5Q